# http://localhost not working but https://localhost working?

Tags: xampp, localhost

i need help 
xampp is working good
but http://localhost not available but https: //localhost is working very good 
how i fix that !?

Comment: It may work if you enter the exact IP address instead of the hostname. Or port 80 is not configured/is blocked while port 443 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may work if you enter the exact IP address instead of the hostname (e.g. `192.168.1.5`)

Either that, or port 80 (for HTTP) is not configured/is blocked while port 443 (for HTTPS) works

If needed you can find a list of commonly used ports [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)